# XWarpPointer does not work on ubuntu 12.04 in wmware player

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, vmware, xlib

Hello i'm trying to move the mouse pointer by using Xlib in my Qt application:

```
cout <<"move mouse to "<<x<<","<<y<<endl;
XWarpPointer(defaultdisplay, None, desktoproot, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, y);
XFlush(defaultdisplay);
//QCursor::setPos(x,y);
```

but this  not work in an ubuntu that is inside a wmware player (maybe vmware tools uses X11), any idea for disabling the vmware mouse integration or using any other code? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found the solucion, all i needed to do is edit the .vmx file in my Ubuntu virtual machine directory and add the line:

```
vmmouse.present = "FALSE"
```

thats disables the mouse integration.