# xdotool mousemove won't work on ubuntu vmware vm

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, xdotool

I installed xdotool on ubuntu 15.10 on a vmware fusion vm on a mac.
I tried running the following commands in the terminal.

```
>xdotool
returns the list of commands.

>xdotool mousemove 200 200 
does not move the mouse, it should move it.

>xdotool type hello 
does work and types hello
```

Is there something wrong with my mousemove command or some reason it will not work in the terminal or in a vm.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on my Kubuntu 16.04 running on vmware. Any findings?

Answer (score 5):

This MAY be an answer :
On an host Linux Mint 17 / guest in Linux Mint 18.1, the mouse doesn't seems to move (visualy, the mouse pointer doesn't move). But if you add a "xdotool click 1", you'll see the click is on the correct mouse position.

Comment: Tested, this on a KVM guest Ubuntu 18.04 and checked mouse position with pyautogui and the mouse was on the correct position

Comment: for fedora 31 is the same issue, the mouse click works on the location that you move but the cursor is not moving, thank you for your post

Comment: Tested on Debian 11 with Mate 1.24.1 - @carlosmarti was right - the mouse does not move but position changed and click happened on the right place

Answer (score 0):

This may be the answer
Edit the .vmx file in  virtual machine directory and add the line:

```
vmmouse.present = "FALSE"
```

[This may works for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553155/xwarppointer-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-12-04-in-wmware-player)